# How to set android:backgroundTint programatically in Widget

Tags: android, widget

I have next widget layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/md_blue_500"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_border_black">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have such drawable (widget_border_black.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dark_gray"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

So drawable draws for me some border (and etc.). 
And android:backgroundTint property colors background with specific color, I provided.

The issue is I want to set any color programatically in adroid widget using RemoteViews class

```
RemoteViews views;
```

I can set:

```
views.setInt(R.id.my_view, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.widget_border_black);
```

It allows me to have widget with border, but without my specific background color
And I can set:

```
views.setInt(R.id.my_view, "setBackgroundColor", note.getColor());
```

It allows me to have widget background color, but without my drawable (border).

Both methods (`setBackgroundResource` and `setBackgroundColor`) are not working at the same! time in widget :(

So, I want to set programatically: `android:backgroundTint` property value (and provide instead of blue color - any!!! color value - not only one, from resource xml)

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/md_blue_500"
```

**The problem is that RemoteViews class doesnt have method for setting backgroundTint property ( such as: `setBackgroundTintList` method of the View class or something else)
How can I resolve my issue?**

Comment: Did you figure this out

Comment: No solution, yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Android 12 now has methods for that: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setColorStateList(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)

Can be used like:

```
remote_view.setColorStateList(R.id.my_view, "setBackgroundTintList", my_color_state_list);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify: How I can set android:backgroundTint="@color/md_blue_500" value programatically with these "new" methods?
(with saving android:background="@drawable/widget_border_black" value)